# Strange behaviours with ActiveRecord Models when returning rows of records to the viewing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my application,

I have the following **MasterActivityCategory** Model, which I retrieve all the master activity categories based on the provided company_id.

```
class MasterActivityCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :activitytypes 

  def self.retrieveCategoriesbyCompany(company_id)
     @categories = self.where(company_id)
     return @categories
  end

end
```

**ActivityCodesController** controller

```
class ActivityCodesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
         @categories = MasterActivityCategory.retrieveCategoriesbyCompany(6)
    end
end
```

Under **views\activity_codes\index.html.erb**

```
<div class="multipage_tab">
<ul>
    <%=@categories.each do|category|%>
    <li>
        <a id="<%=category.name.downcase%>" href="#">
        <%=category.name%>
        </a>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

I did get the correct output on screen as expected.  But when I checked the source, i notice it added another lines of code at the bottom (as view from page source in Chrome), (see below).

```
<div class="multipage_tab">
                            <ul>

                                <li>
                                    <a id="personal" href="#">
                                        Personal
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a id="corporate" href="#">
                                        Corporate
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a id="overheads" href="#">
                                        Overheads
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a id="disbursements" href="#">
                                        Disbursements
                                    </a>
                                </li>
[#&lt;MasterActivityCategory id: 1, name: "Personal", company_id: 6, created_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40", updated_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40"&gt;, #&lt;MasterActivityCategory id: 2, name: "Corporate", company_id: 6, created_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40", updated_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40"&gt;, #&lt;MasterActivityCategory id: 3, name: "Overheads", company_id: 6, created_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40", updated_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40"&gt;, #&lt;MasterActivityCategory id: 4, name: "Disbursements", company_id: 6, created_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40", updated_at: "2014-03-24 00:07:40"&gt;]                             </ul>
</div>
```

I couldn't understand where' this extra line of ActiveRecord come from.  In my view page code, I already loop four times to retrieve the Master Activity codes values from the table and display the records under each li tag.  But why did that last item sneak in?

It doesnt make any sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe where you have this line:

```
<%=@categories.each do|category|%>
```

You'll need to change the `=` to a `-` or remove it all together. eg:

```
<% @categories.each do|category|%>
```

It's rendering the enumerated records.

Comment: or just remove it altogether.  <% @categories.each do |category| %>

Comment: Oh Thanks! That probably explains a huge reason!! Cheers!

Comment: Edited the answer to add that you can also remove it all together as noted by emcanes.